# ASP.NET MVC 3 (Razor) form submit not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Using Fiddler I can see that the request is not even being made but I can't see why.

Here's the form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "FileSystemChannelIndex", FormMethod.Post, new {
channelId = @Model.ChannelId }))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ChannelId)
    <div class="editor-label">
        Select File Source
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(
            model => model.SelectedFileSourceValue,
            new SelectList(Model.AvailableFilesSources, "Id", "Name"),
            new { id = "selectFileSource" })
    </div>
    <p>
        <input class="t-button" type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
}
```

The View originally came from:

```
public ViewResult Create(int channelId)
{   
    var channel = this.fullUOW.GetFileSystemChannelRepository().All.Where(c => c.Id == channelId);
    var vm = new FileSystemChannelIndexViewModel(channelId, new FileSystemChannelIndex());
    return View("Edit", vm);
}
```

I've tried adding the "name" attribute to the  but that didn't make any difference.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** More info for Jim et al...

Domain:

```
public class FileSystemChannel
{
   public int Id {get; set; }
   public ICollection<FileSystemChannelIndex> ChannelIndexes { get; set; }
}

public class FileSystemChannelIndex
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public FileSystemChannel ParentChannel { get; set; }
}
```

Due to a 0...* association, in the UI we have to create a FileSystemChannel first then add a FileSystemChannelIndex to it. So that's why I pass in the channelId to the FileSystemChannelIndex Create View. When submitting the new FileSystemChannelIndex the following action should be called:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(int channelId, FileSystemChannelIndexViewModel vm)
{
    //TODO: get the Channel, add the Index, save to db

    return View("Index");
}
```

Comment: Do you have an ActionResult called Index  with `[HttpPost]` data annotation?

Comment: you must be getting some errors? what are those errors?

Comment: @Tim Yep, though I'm not sure if the signature is correct.

Comment: @3nigma - there are no obvious errors, can you suggest where I should be looking?

Comment: empo - can you post both `public ActionResult Create(/**/)` methods (i.e. `HttpPost` and `HttpGet`) into the question as this could highlight if the issue is related to ambiguous method signatures, which i suspect could well be the case as you are posting back the same signature as the HttpGet actionresult

Comment: May be the validations(client side)  stopping the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So thanks to Mark's comment it's due to a Select failing client side validation. Using IE dev tools to inspect the element:

```
<select name="SelectedFileSourceValue" class="input-validation-error" id="selectFileSource" data-val-required="The SelectedFileSourceValue field is required." data-val-number="The field SelectedFileSourceValue must be a number." data-val="true">
```

Answer (score 1):

empo,

further to my comment above:

*empo - can you post both `public ActionResult Create(////)` methods (i.e. `HttpPost` and `HttpGet`) into the question as this could highlight if the issue is related to ambiguous method signatures, which i suspect could well be the case as you are posting back the same signature as the HttpGet actionresult*

try adding the appropriate HttpPost actionresult along the lines of:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FileSystemChannelIndex domainModel)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(PopulateEditViewModel(domainModel));
    }

    _serviceTasks.Insert(domainModel);
    _serviceTasks.SaveChanges();
    return this.RedirectToAction("Edit", new {id = domainModel.ChannelId});
}
```

your original HttpGet (which feels 'wierd' to me):

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult Create(int channelId) {   
    var channel = this.fullUOW.GetFileSystemChannelRepository().All
       .Where(c => c.Id == channelId);
    var vm = new FileSystemChannelIndexViewModel(channelId, 
        new FileSystemChannelIndex());
    return View("Edit", vm); 
}
```

and inside your Edit actionresult, you'd grab the entity based on the passed in id. might work, might not. not sure without a fuller picture of your domain and logic.

obviously, your own plumbing will vary, but this should give an idea of what should be expected.

Comment: Jim, see my edit above. I didn't think it was due to the controller though because the page is not even making a request.

Comment: Jim there is no [HttpPost] Create because I want to return to the Index view, as you can see in the Html.BeginForm parameters. I'm starting to think I got this all wrong and should have a Create action which is called but return the Index view

Comment: empo- i think you've possibly got it wrong if using index as a httppost action. the standard practice is to have a 'pair' of actions, one that GETs to required objects and values for the post, the other that accepts the POSTed values and then does a redirect (PRG).

Answer (score 0):

How can you have Model.Id when you are creating something? Maybe Model.Id is null and because you cannot post

Comment: it's the same view for create and edit. if id = 0 then create if id > 0 then edit

Comment: why do you need this? new {
channelId = @Model.ChannelId }

Comment: channelId Hidden field will be posted

Comment: I was trying different things to work out why the action wasn't being called and didn't remove it from my sample code.